# Docker lowest capabilities

Tags: docker

I want to run a docker container. This container must be isolated from the host computer.

This means the container should not access to files and memory of the host computer.

The container will only access to network throught mapped port (-p option) and nat.

So i run this command:

```
docker run -it --cap-drop ALL myimage
```

There is something very strange because i can't run a basic command like "apt-get update" on the container.

I have setgroups, seteuid errors.

I do not understand why i have to add capabilities for that !

I understand docker needs capabilities on the container, for the container itself. But i do not want to allow capabilities on the host system.

How should i do to disable all capabilities for host interaction and allow all capabilities for the container itself ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That sounds like you're describing a virtual-machine setup.  Docker containers are reasonably well isolated from the host, but some things like the kernel are shared, and "capabilities for the container but not the host" doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the sequence where you're running APT inside the container, though; anything you change this way will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's in your image's Dockerfile?  What process is the container running?  What are the actual error messages?